# Any versions of g++ as library?

Tags: gcc, g++

I am developing a 'thing' that must be able to compile arbitrary plugins at runtime as shared objects. While it is possible to programmatically call  ::system("g++ -std=c++0x ... -o whatever.so"), spawning processes this way is not retained secure by the policies I am bound to. I was searching for some sort of g++ version as a shared object, in order to static link the 'thing' to it at compile time and use an ABI to request builds at runtime; but no luck since now. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). Note that despite the name, it can also be used for AoT compilation. An alternative is clang/llvm (in library form).